# Convert background-position % to px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know how to convert `brackground-position` from percentage to px.

At some point I use `background-size: contain`, which resizes the image.

***Jsfiddle:***

https://jsfiddle.net/tng3spqb/1/

***EX:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("RED: BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".box").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".box").css("backgroundPositionY")+"\n"+"BLACK - NOT BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".all").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".all").css("backgroundPositionY")+"\n"+"GREEN: BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".box2").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".box2").css("backgroundPositionY")+"\n"+"PINK: NOT BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".all2").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".all2").css("backgroundPositionY"))
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('http://www.guiaturismo.net/blog/wp-content/gallery/fotos-ilha-grande/fotos-ilha-grande-1.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
}

.all {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('http://www.guiaturismo.net/blog/wp-content/gallery/fotos-ilha-grande/fotos-ilha-grande-1.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.all2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: pink;
  background-image: url('https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
  margin-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="all">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="all2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `background-position` X and Y positions with something like below. Is that what your looking for?

```
$(".box").css({ "background-position-x": "60px" });
$(".box").css({ "background-position-y": "60px" });
```

**Update code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("RED: BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".box").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".box").css("backgroundPositionY")+"\n"+"BLACK - NOT BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".all").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".all").css("backgroundPositionY")+"\n"+"GREEN: BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".box2").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".box2").css("backgroundPositionY")+"\n"+"PINK: NOT BACKGROUND CONTAIN: "+$(".all2").css("backgroundPositionX")+" - "+$(".all2").css("backgroundPositionY"))
 

 // how about something like this?
 $(".box").css({ "background-position-x": "60px" });
 $(".box").css({ "background-position-y": "60px" });
 
 alert("RED: BACKGROUND CONTAIN X: "+$(".box").css("backgroundPositionX"));
 alert("RED: BACKGROUND CONTAIN Y: "+$(".box").css("backgroundPositionY"));
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('http://www.guiaturismo.net/blog/wp-content/gallery/fotos-ilha-grande/fotos-ilha-grande-1.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
}

.all {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('http://www.guiaturismo.net/blog/wp-content/gallery/fotos-ilha-grande/fotos-ilha-grande-1.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.all2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: pink;
  background-image: url('https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
  margin-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="all">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="all2">
</div>
```

Comment: Dear, as the program has divs with different sizes and images with different sizes, I can not set in px. I could, but would have to perform calculations containing the image sizes and the size of the div. An alternative that I found for what I wanted to accomplish was the following: `$(".result").css({ 'backgroundPositionX': 'calc('+$(".result").css('backgroundPositionX')+' - 1px)' }); ` . ATT